# Anatomy of a SharePoint 2010 Master Page? Resource for this?

Tags: master-page, css, custom-masterpage

I am interested in finding out detailed information about all the elements within the SharePoint master page v4 to start, in order to learn how to create my own while still retaining key functionality.

I have been unable to find something that breaksdown all the ids and classes and what they end up becoming. Master page elements and coreV4.css styles would be most helpful.

Anyone know where I can find this type of info, or resource for this.

Appreciate as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Starter Master Pages](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/) is a great resource for learning about SharePoint 2010 master pages and a good starting point for SharePoint 2010 branding projects

From _starter_publishing.master

```
<!-- s4-ca is the main body div -->
    <div class="s4-ca">

        <div class="s4-notdlg">
            <!-- links for I like it and Tags and Notes -->
            <!-- use ControlID="GlobalSiteLink3" for larger icons or remove this line entirely for no icons -->
            <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink3-mini" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/>
        </div>

        <div class="s4-notdlg">
            <!-- page title -->
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" />          
        </div>

        <!-- place a table around this to handle funky markup in _Layouts/areacachesettings.aspx (if you want) -->
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server" />

        <div>
            <!-- page content loads from the pages and pages layout -->
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Starter master pages for SharePoint 2010 could be found [here](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/releases/view/41533)

Answer (score 1):

To make a custom master page I recommend you to start from the V4. Make sure that you don't delete any content place holder from the original master. If you don't want to use some of them on your custom master you should hide it through CSS.